# php is saying .01 is not greater than 0. Why?

Tags: php

I have a simple setup in my cart that charges a flat rate for shipping if the weight is less than 5 lbs but not zero. I use zero weights for free shipping. It works perfectly, except the weights below 1.000 are not getting set to the 7.10 rate.

```
 if($weight>.001 && $weight<5)
              {            
               $handling=7.10;
              }
```

This is in PHP.

I can paste the whole code, but it is huge. If there is a string or float or array setting I need to invoke that i'm missing here, please let me know. If you need the whole code, I can do that too.

Comment: What are the exact contents & type of `$weight`?  Inspect via `var_dump($weight);`

Comment: Why the `.001` and not just `0`

Comment: Maybe you will have to convert `$weight` to `(float) $weight`, but `$weight > 0` would also do the same logic, if the data type is correct.

Comment: Daan - I changed it from zero to try and get numbers below 1 to work. It didn't change anything. var_dump yields - float(.05) if the weight is .05 lbs.

Comment: What version of php are you using? The same code seems to be working fine in 5.4+ - http://ideone.com/URzRgO.

Comment: Double check your `$weight` value and checkout @AlexSzabó's suggestion.

Comment: Double check it for what? It returns flot (.05) if the weight is .05. I saw Alex's comment, he said it should work. I also tried putting "float" before the $weight, and it sis the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($weight>.001 && $weight<5)
           ^^^^
```

The `.001` is not working. You can write `0.001` if you wand a float or your write it as string ".001".
Or you write it something like this `(float)".001"` then you cast the string to a float.

Comment: Float comparisons aren't trustable. Make unit tests comparing 0.001 vs 0.002 and stuff like it and you will get more than one surprise, most of the languages does not recommend comparing floating numbers.